# How to fix docker dns problems?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, dns

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env

  main:
    container_name: tm_main
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

I have some docker-compose.yml file, when i run docker i'm getting an error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres`.
Here is .env file

```
PORT=3000

DATABASE_HOST=postgres
DATABASE_USER=user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
DATABASE_NAME=docker_problem_db
DATABASE_PORT=5432
JWT_REFRESH_SECRET="refreshVeryHardSecret"
JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE=86000
```

I use for database manager Beekeeper Studio and when i try to connect database with host postgres getting same error, but when change hostname into 'localhost' everything is wokring.

I want to connect to database through hostname, i read a lot of about dns problems but i can't fix it, please help me.

Even when I try this:

```
docker run --name acid -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres:13
```

I can't connect to database through database manager with credentials:

```
hostname=acid
user=postgres
password=postgres
```

But i can connect like this:

```
docker exec -it acid psql -U postgres
```

docker inspect shows:

```
          "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "0166c61f6a5aea83490fc8c598af04e55df71f9009e336684542f922b4c042cd",
                    "EndpointID": "8c11cc65305666dee3786ad23453b981230adc2bd654aee4b8312fe5f54c074b",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

And here is networkes list

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                   DRIVER    SCOPE
0166c61f6a5a   bridge                 bridge    local
491c2f61e8d2   host                   host      local
33ac66fb767c   mynetwork              bridge    local
8233fba80fe2   nest-backend_default   bridge    local
6cc450ff3353   none                   null      local
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Compose doesn't read PNG-format files, and without seeing the code directly in the question it's almost impossible to tell what might be going wrong.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], as plain text and not images, directly in the question and not behind links?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated question, sorry this is my first post

Comment: Double-checking two things: you're running the container via `docker-compose up` and not individual `docker run` commands; and `docker-compose build` on its own runs successfully?

Comment: Yes i know difference between `docker-compose up` and `docker run` i just try to show you more about my problem. Problem is when i run containers i can't connect to containers via hostname or ip address, when i try connect via hostname it shows error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <hostname>` and when i try connect via ip it just waiting and returning error with timeout.

But i can connect to container through `docker exec`

Answer (score -1):

you haven't defined the hostname in your compose.
You can add `hostname: postgres` in `services.postgres` below `container_name` based on the images you included.

Happy coding!

Comment: Compose `hostname:` does almost nothing, and doesn't affect container DNS at all.  You almost never need to set `hostname:` and it's usually safe to delete it if it is set.  (RabbitMQ is one very specific exception to this.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).